# Place ImageView beside the TextView

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I think the solution will be quite obvious, but as long as I'm rookie in android forgive me :)

I want to place some picture on the right upper side of the view, and a textview, which will fit the rest of the view. Here's what I've done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_in_listing"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dip"
            android:background="@drawable/border_for_imageview"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook_logo" />

          <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/someString"
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/logo_in_listing"
            android:layout_margin="3dip"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's what I get:

[image]

My questions:

1) How to make the textview fit also the lower part of imageview? I don't want that space to be left unused.

2) As you see, I've used `dip`s for placing ImageView. What would you recommend in this case? I mean, how to write in a way, that it will be same for all screen sizes? Or maybe `dip` is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Spanned` interface. [Here's](http://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/downloads/detail?name=FlowTextDemo.zip) a good example

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How to make the textview fit also the lower part of imageview? I
>   don't want that space to be left unused.

*Flow around* text isn't possible with currently available layouts. However you can display content as HTML in a WebView or even spanned-HTML in a TextView.

> 2) As you see, I've used dips for placing ImageView. What would you
>   recommend in this case? I mean, how to write in a way, that it will be
>   same for all screen sizes? Or maybe dip is OK?

Dip is for device independent pixels. On different screen sizes, 1 Dip will take different number of pixels, but visually, 1 dip will appear almost same to eye on all screens.

Answer (score 0):

If You don´t want to left space, You could use spannables. For example:

```
    int TEXT_START  = 0;
    int TEXT_END = yourTextView.length();
    Spannable span = (Spannable) yourtextview.getText();
    span.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), TEXT_START, TEXT_END,
            0);
```

For Your second Question: use dp instead of dip.

Comment: I believe `dp` and `dip` are same things.

Comment: yes it is, but I read some threads about problems using dip. It seems that not every device is accepting dip.